# Nginx в phpmyadmin не отображаются иконки и съехала верстка, как это можно исправить?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, nginx, phpmyadmin

Конфиг Nginx

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name ...;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
```

У меня изменен url для phpmyadmin, но файлы берет из usr/share/phpmyadmin вот вывод с команды ls -l

```
cd /var/www/html/
ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 612 Mar 24 14:56 index.nginx-debian.html
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  21 Mar 24 15:04 name -> /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может, [не надо](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/security/stop-installing-phpmyadmin)? Любой GUI клиент для MySQL проще и быстрее в установке и настройке, а главное удобнее в работе. Плюс безопаснее.

Answer (score 0):

Все таки проблема была из-за смены url, странно конечно.

Решение:
В конфигурационный файл добавил

```
location /тут путь где находится phpmyadmin {
    alias /usr/share/phpMyAdmin;
    index index.php;
}
```